# Rationale for the LM2904 Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, datasheet

A while ago I came across a great deal on a reel of [LM2904](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm258a.pdf) op-amps. Although I certainly didn't need several thousand TSSOPs, I was able to happily convince myself that, as a family man, I would be saving money in the long run (we've all done it).

Anyway, while I love the supply, everytime I reach for one I find myself wishing it had been a reel of *LM358* instead.

The *LM2904* seems to be basically the same as the *LM358*, except where it falls slightly short in a few areas. *Eg. Max Vcc*. Otherwise, you have to look very closely to find any differences at all - especially when comparing against the *V* version (*LM2904V*) of the chip.

**1.** My question therefore is, why is the *LM2904* still in full production?

What is the point of it? Why would someone choose it when the *LM358* is a drop-in replacement and is arguably a little better?

**2.** For extra credit - why is it called *LM2904*? This one has always bugged me. Is this a legacy number? It seems odd to have a datasheet for the *LM158, LM258, LM358, and the LM2904*.

It's been a while since I last watched *Sesame Street*, but it reminds me of their "One of these things is not like the other" game.

Comment: A guess: National Semi attempted to cook up LM358, but too many didn't quite make the grade: result - LM2904. Popularity keeps it going for "good enough" engineers.

Comment: @glen_geek Maybe. Although others make the LM2904 as well: On Semi and ST are at the top of my Google search. In fact, when I set out to write this question, I was planning to include V_lo as a parameter difference, because I know that's true of the ST line. However, I was surprised to find that this parameter was equivalent (between the two chips) in the TI datasheet. So, the TI implementation seems to maybe be better than some of the others.

Comment: @BlairFonville Hint: Octopart.com is a nice search engine for parts; https://octopart.com/search?q=lm2904&avg_avail=(1__*)&start=0&sort=median_price_1000&sort-dir=asc lists all available LM2904, and those include TI, ST, ON (and fairchild, separately, so there's still stock from back of these days), Diodes Inc, Rohm, National Semiconductor (which is now part of TI), Intersil (which is a part of Renesas), NXP (in fact, these are probably still Philips branded) and Motorola (probably from the times before the spun off ON semi). So, these parts have been produced by **everyone**

Comment: … **everyone** who has a semiconductor fab to keep running in between. I guess the LM2904 is so easy to manufacture that it's one of the things you produce whenever you need to recalibrate machinery. National Semi invented the "LM" naming, so it's fair to assume they first named an opamp 2904.

Comment: I'd suggest the LM2904 is a much better chip than the LM358 ...it is a full range (-40 - +125 degC) device that is automotive certified. The fact that the voltage range is restricted is probably to meet the better output source/sink current flow maxima.  The LM258/358 are the cheapie commercial range product.

Comment: @JackCreasey the original National Semi 158/258/358/2904 datasheet says -40 to +85 °C, not +125°C. But my guess would be that all these are the same chips, differing only in testing and test results

Comment: @JackCreasey http://web.mit.edu/6.115/www/document/lm158.pdf

Comment: @MarcusMüller. I definitely agree, it's just binning ...but would say the LM2904 is the best bin. OnSemi have the temp out to -40 - +125 for the LM2904 ....so just more bins.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That's the pdf I should have linked. It's the one I have saved and refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. My question therefore is, why is the LM2904 still in full production?
>
> What is the point of it? Why would someone choose it when the LM358 is a drop-in replacement and is arguably a little better?

Generally, cheapness. If the LM2904 is 0.1ct cheaper in 10000 pcs and you don't need anything that the LM358 has to offer – why spend that $100 ?

Other than that, I don't want to rule out that LM2904s you can buy are decades old (you can actually find stocks with photos of Philips-branded LM2904 – and Philips semiconductors was renamed NXP 2006. And those definitely aren't the oldest to the bunch). So, no evidence they are actually still in production.

Furthermore, it's very likely that the LM2904 are in fact from LM358 wafers – maybe parts on the wafer that didn't quite achieve gains, or didn't get tested thoroughly, or just LM358 that you'd rather sell than keep in stock. At this point, I'm not even convinced that "modern" LM358 are different than LM158 aside from being less intensely tested, or showing different parameters during testing.

Notice that semiconductor fabs make most money with expensive, small-feature devices. But: your fab might become old, or there might be a break between production of high-profit parts, so you produce just "whatever" to not let your fab (and thus, your investment) stand around. Old Opamps are a prime candidate for that – the structures are "huge" by modern standards, ie. even a badly calibrated lithography can still produce them reliably, they are still sold in the millions, and the masks are already in storage. Win!

> 2. For extra credit - why is it called LM2904? This one has always bugged me. Is this a legacy number? It seems odd to have a datasheet for the LM158, LM258, LM358, and the LM2904.

So, in LM**2**904, 2 is usually the temperature range – industrial. And that works out here, -40° to 85°. In fact, it exceeds the temperature range of the LM358. So maybe, it was, or is, just a more temperature-tested version of the LM358.

But why the four-digit code at all? No idea. Maybe it was meant as LM**2.9**08? (note: there's also 2902s).

Comment: Since the LM2904 is the same silicon, it's highly unlikely that you will get old stock just based on the number. The LM2904 is the only device in the range on the datasheet that meets automotive standards ....that alone is a good reason to keep supplying it. As in the comments above this is all about binning parts and the LM2904 would always be the more expensive.

Comment: @JackCreasey LM158 exceeds the temp ranges of LM2904, but when does one need -55°C (opposed to -40°C) in automotive? So, yeah, LM2904 is probably the most bought part, and the best-binned, if it wasn't for the reduced gain rating – but that might simply be the difference between LM158 and LM2904 – the LM158 guarantees a min large voltage gain of 50 V/V, whereas the LM2904 only guarantees 25 – but it might really be just luck whether a chip does a high gain at extreme temperatures, so that, again, might just be binning.

Comment: "So, no evidence they are actually still in production". Maybe. TI lists the part as "Active", which I read to mean "still in production". Although I don't discount your point. Great answer. Thanks.

Comment: @BlairFonville well, "active" is a fair point. But I'd say "active" means "if you place an order for n· 10⁵ devices, we'll get the mask out of storage and fulfill that. Aside from that, we and/or distributors still have > 10⁶ piece on stock"

Comment: Somehow I neglected to accept this.

Answer (score 1):

They produce lm358 for the suckers and 2904 for the wise shoppers who are unwilling to pay more for the same parts.

Buying and using 2904 says to the world that you know what you are talking about.

Comment: I don't mind that explanation. For all we know, it's true :)